# Can ADO.NET create its own basic validation by reflecting the database structure?

Tags: validation, reflection, ado.net

I am now to the stage of adding validation to a simple app for editing a few SQL tables via data-bound controls. I can see that the BindingSource knows the limits of the table's structure: if I enter, for example, letters in a field that should contain only decimals, up pops a DataError exception with the message that you can only enter decimals there.

It seems to me that ADO.NET should be able to use reflection to generate basic validation for all the data-bound fields. But after a lot of Googling, I see only people creating their own validation by column by column.

Can I use ADO.NET's knowledge of the database structure to have it make some of the basic validation for me (e.g. data type, text field length limits)? Do you have some examples?

Comment: I realize a "cheat" way to do this would be to catch the DataError exceptions and prettify them for the end-user. But that's probably not wise.

Comment: Bueller? Bueller? Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sad that I've never gotten a good response on this question... but I think I have my answer:

***Yes***, it should be possible, but *no*, it hasn't been done yet.

(Maybe someday I'll start a project myself to make a tool which would auto-generate basic validation values for data-bound form fields.)